# Authorize.net Form Security

Tags: e-commerce, payment, authorize.net, payment-processing

Let me preface the question by stating that I'm not a programmer and am requesting a response that an infant could grasp.

I'm building a payment form via Authorize.net using the PHP SIM method. I've noticed that the hidden fields of the form (which contain my API Login ID and Transaction Key) are visible in the source code. Obviously this is not good.

The only solution I've found to keep them hidden is to pull in the values from a secure external file during the POST of the form.

Sounds logical, but how do I do this? What does that look like in PHP? Have mercy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The transaction key is **not** visible in the source code of the form. The API login is but that's ok. The transaction key, along with the API login and other criteria which are dynamic and unique to the transaction, are included with the form in the form of a MD5 hash and cannot be guessed or created by hackers. This is safe and secure.

You *really* should hire a programmer to do this for you. Ecommerce isn't something a non-programmer should even *think* about playing with. This is how lives are ruined.

Comment: if it is converted to md(5) then how could they (authorize.net) decrypt the value as hashing is one way

Comment: Because Authorize.net has all of the same information you do and can create the hash themselves and compare it to yours. If they match the transaction has not been tampered with.